# SVN repository issue

Tags: linux, svn, netbeans, tortoisesvn, repository

I've created a `svn` repository on a `linux` computer. For this repository I've also created a working copy named `myfirstproject`. In order to get the URL of it I've typed in "`svn` info". The answer was

**`"svn://localhost/myfirstproject".`**

Now I want to approach this working copy from windows computer. I've tried doing it via `netbeans` for the first time and `tortoiseSVN` as well. I've tried to approach **`svn://my_server_domainName/myfirstproject`**, but it was failed.

For instance, I am trying to set the URL on "repo-browser" option on tortoriseSVN or if I try to perform Checkout on netbeans, then the messages I recieve on both is "Unable to connect to a repository URL..." and "Can't connect to host ... :A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond".

what should I suppose to do? Is there any other URL address I need to type?

Thank you

Comment: You need to either setup a  subversion server (maybe svnserve)  or share the directory where is is an access it via something like SMB/CIFS.

Comment: Did you post this question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656109/cant-approach-svn-working-copy

Comment: Do *not* share the directory. It will allow anyone to arbitrarily manipulate or even delete the repository data. Set up a server using svnserve or apache, the svn manual tells you how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

SVN supports 3 types of protocol:

- http://
- file://
- svn://

try with the other options like:

```
file://my_server_domainName/myfirstproject
http://my_server_domainName/myfirstproject
```